# Angular-ui-router state.transitionTo routes to an empty:id (/users//)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

where It should route to `/users/me/` and Instead it routes to `/users//`
if I manually write the `/users/me/` url or use a link to move there, everything works fine. but transitionTo doesn't Do what I expect and I can't figure out why.

In my code I have:

```
$state.transitionTo('users.me');
```

where in my routes(states) config I have:

```
state('users', {
            abstract:true,

            templateUrl: '/path/to/template.html',

            access: { isPrivate: 0 },
            resolve: {
           ...a resolve block..



    }).state('users.me',{
            url: '/users/:id/',
            controller: 'userCtrl',
            access: { isPrivate: 0 },
            views:{
                'userView':{
                    templateUrl:'/path/to/template.html'',
                    controller:'userCtrl',

                },
                'view1':{
                    templateUrl:'/path/to/template.html'',
                    controller:'anotherCtrl',

                },
                'view2':{
                    templateUrl:'/path/to/template.html'',
                    controller:'anotherCtrl',

                },
                'view3':{
                    templateUrl:'/path/to/template.html'',
                    controller:'anotherCtrl',

                },
                'view4':{
                    templateUrl:'/path/to/template.html',
                    controller:'anotherCtrl'
                }
            }
```

I'll be glad for help with this

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Make sure you provide an id.

```
$state.transitionTo('users.me', {'id': 'me'});
```

This should make it work, but you should be using the `go()` method as transitionTo is a low-level function since 0.2.0.

```
$state.go('users.me', {'id': 'me'});
```

Be sure to read [the method's documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#statetransitiontoto-toparams--options).

Comment: To be clear, `transitionTo()` is *not* an internal function, it is simply a more explicit and verbose one, whereas `go()` does a bunch of things automatically.

Comment: One of those things go() handles automatically is passing along all your existing URL's params, ie. only as far as params are concerned, .go('bob') is equivalent to transitionTo('bob', $stateParams).

Answer (score 0):

in your case you should use `$state.go('users.me', {'id': 1});`

$state.go(to [, toParams] [, options])

Returns a Promise representing the state of the transition.

Convenience method for transitioning to a new state. $state.go calls $state.transitionTo internally but automatically sets options to { location: true, inherit: true, relative: $state.$current, notify: true }. This allows you to easily use an absolute or relative to path and specify only the parameters you'd like to update (while letting unspecified parameters inherit from the current state).

$state.transitionTo(to, toParams [, options])

Returns a Promise representing the state of the transition.

Low-level method for transitioning to a new state. $state.go() uses transitionTo internally. $state.go() is recommended in most situations.